# Como puedo correr un suite test en la misma ventana?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit-4

Yo cree un suite test en el cual están hilados 2 test: Uno para loguearse y el otro para suscribirse, el problema es que al momento de ejecutar la suite abre 2 ventanas de Chrome para el cada proceso y yo necesito que la sesión este iniciada para realizar la suscripción.

Las 2 ventanas no se comunican entre ellas y falla el código para la compra.
Como puedo ejecutar la suite en la misma ventana pero con diferentes pestanas?

intente buscar una Chrome option pero no puede, pero estoy seguro de que existe una para realizar lo que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado dale una vuelta a Testng, el cual te permite ejecutar distintos test en varios metodos, de los cuales puedes tener 1 clase con 2 test  1 para login y otro para suscribirte sin cerrar el navegador.
Si buscas abrir otra ventana debes crear 1 clase para cada test, que se van a ejecutar de forma secuencial.

Nota: Cuidado con las precondiciones.

Comment: Alex Bravo, de que manera puedo crear una clase que contenga 2 test?

Comment: Por ejemplo tienes una clase CPA01_IngresoLogin en dicha clase tendrás 2 métodos y arriba de cada metodo sus @test. Ya con eso tendras 2 pruebas dentro de 1 clase.